# How can I remove Gesture recognizer in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm not sure how to remove the gesture recognizers. Many thanks guys.

> [image: How can I remove these??]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select && Press `delete`.

Comment: I tried that initially, for some reason it didn't work but now it does LOL. THANKS

Comment: @nicael sounds good, this was just flagged as a low quality post by SO

Answer (score 2):

Nicael's answer applies to Xcode 8 as well.  Below is a more thorough procedure:

1. Open Project Navigator and select Main.storyboard this should display the Image Navigator to the right
2. Find the "Gesture Recognizer" in the Image Navigator on top of the Scene as in picture

   > [image: action icons of a Scene]

   (the third icon form the left)
3. Select the Gesture Recognizer icon and press the "delete" key as in picture

   > [image: Select the Gesture Recognizer icon]
4. Open the "Assistant Editor" or "Standard Editor" to locate the Gesture Recognizer code section in the Swift project and remove it.